# Reading a cookie from a WCF RESTful webservice

Tags: wcf, rest, cookies

Writing a suite of IIS hosted WCF webservices (both GET and POST), and I need to be able to read a cookie for an authentication token so I know the user has been auth'd previously.

Will HttpContext.Current.Cookies give me what I need or is there something cleaner and more appropriate for a WCF web service with WebGet and WebInvoke attributes?

Answer (score 4):

```
string cookieHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie];
```

works for me

Comment: if i call this wcf service from another domain then , will i get my domain cookie????